# Total convergence of this series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to study the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{((n+2)!)^{x+1}}.$$
I observe that, having
$$f_n(x) =\frac{(2n)!}{((n+2)!)^{x+1}},$$
it is
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}f_n(x)=0 \quad\mbox{ if } x>0$$
thus the series could converge if and only if $x>0$. I start studying the absolute convergence.
I note that, taking $x>0$, it follows
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \left\vert\frac{(2n)!}{((n+2)!)^{x+1}}\right\vert =\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{((n+2)!)^{x+1}}$$
and by applying the ratio criterion I have
$$\frac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}\sim \frac{1}{n^x},$$
so that I have absolute convergence if $x>1$.
I proceed studying the total convergence. It is
$$\|f_n\|_{\infty}=\sup_{x>1}|f_n(x)|=\sup_{x>1}f_n(x).$$

My questions are: It is correct my procedure so far? If yes, how to study the total convergence?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean with total convergence: $\sup_{x>1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)<\infty$ or $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{x>1} f_n(x)<\infty$ or something else?

Comment: The second one definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarification, you want to know whether
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{x>1}f_n(x)$$
is finite or not. Importantly note that
$$\sup_{x>1}f_n(x)=f_n(1)=\frac{(2n)!}{((n+2)!)^2},$$
because
$$x\mapsto f_n(x)=\frac{(2n)!}{((n+2)!)^{x+1}}$$
increases as $x\to1.$ You already observed that
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  f_n(1)$$
diverges to $\infty$. Indeed, note that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{f_{n+1}(1)}{f_n(1)}\right|=4>1$$
holds, thus we have divergence by the Ratio rest. Hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sup_{x>1}f_n(x)$$
diverges to $\infty$ as well.

Comment: Possibly there is a mistake when you evaluate $f_n(1)$?

Comment: You are right, my mistake. The conclusion still holds, I will edit my post.